# What is the difference between using a unit and not using one?

Tags: f#

I am curious as to what is the major significance, if any in regards to taking a unit or not in code similar to below. What are the advantages or disadvantages. To my current understanding, taking a unit will implement a function that returns a value while not taking one just simply represents the value. Looking for some clarity here.

code without Unit:

```
    let consumerKey = 

        // retrieve keys
        query{
            for row in db.Keys do
            select {
                consumerKey = row.ConsumerKey;
                consumerSecret = row.ConsumerSecret
            }
            exactlyOneOrDefault
        }
```

code with Unit:

```
    let consumerKey() = 

        // retrieve keys
        query{
            for row in db.Keys do
            select {
                consumerKey = row.ConsumerKey;
                consumerSecret = row.ConsumerSecret
            }
            exactlyOneOrDefault
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block of code binds a value of type `query<_>` to identifier `consumerKey` while the second binds a value of type `() -> query<_>` to identifier `consumerKey`. The second is a function which when given `unit` will return a value of type `query<_>`.

In this example, the difference between the two are explicitly captured by their signatures. In other words, the first can be obtained from the second by invoking the function value with `()`. In terms of runtime, the second will always return a new underlying object instance, while the first one is fixed.

In cases where the evaluation causes side effects, the same would not hold. For example in thw following:

```
let value1 = Guid.NewGuid()
let value2 () = Guid.NewGuid()
```

A `value1` cannot be obtained via `value2` because a different value would be returned for each invocation.